# How to store sensitive information in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to store some sensitive information in a table in SQL Server 2008.
The data is a string and I do not want it to be in human readable format to anyone accessing the database.

What I mean by sensitive information is, a database of dirty/foul words. I need to make sure that they are not floating around in tables and SQL files. 
At the same time, I should be able to perform operations like "=" and "like" on the strings.

So far I can think of two options; will these work or what is a better option?

1. Store string (varchar)  as binary data (BLOB)
2. Store in some encrypted format, like we usually do with passwords.

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third option, which may be most appropriate, is to simply not store these values in the particular database at all. I would argue that it is probably more appropriate to store them elsewhere, since you're probably not going to JOIN against the table of sensitive words.

Otherwise, you *probably* want to use Conrad Frix's suggestion of SQL Server's built-in encryption support.

The reason I say this is because you say both = and LIKE must work across your data. When you hash a string using a hash algo such as SHA/MD5/etc., the results won't obey human language LIKE semantics.

If exact equality (=) is sufficient (i.e. you don't really need to be able to do LIKE queries), you can use a cryptographic function to secure the text. But keep in mind that a one-way hash function would prohibit you from getting a list of strings "un-hashed" - if you need to do that, you need to use an encryption algo where decryption is possible, such as AES.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [rot13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), then you can still use = and LIKE.  This also applies to any storage method other than an SQL database, if preventing casual/accidental views (including search engine indexing, if the list is public) is that important.

Comment: Upvoted. I think ROT13 is a perfectly simple solution to this problem. Obscurity (as opposed to encryption) is reasonable because the data is not private, only "offensive". ROT13 is simple, quasi-standard, and retains compatibility with = and LIKE, as the OP requested.